# Why are Children always so interested in adults?

Tags: developmental-psychology, evolutionary-psychology

I work as a kindergarten teacher, and it's always fascinating to me that children are so quick to be affectionate and take interest in what their teacher is doing.  Is there an evolutionary reason for this behaviour? Are children genetically programmed from birth to be loving and to affect the emotional bonds of adults around them, in order to receive more resources (food, shelter, etc., for survival)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better off at Parenting.SE

Comment: Alternatively, Matt, if you were to redirect the question to a more developmental psychology frame, such as asking "when does children's interest in adults wane" or "are there specific adult activities that children are interested in", it would still be an acceptable question.